# Python maximum and minimum

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a function max_and_min that accepts a tuple containing integer elements as an argument and returns the largest and smallest integer within the tuple. The return value should be a tuple containing the largest and smallest value, in that order.

for the 'normal' method, i came up with:

```
def max_and_min(values):
    return (max(values), min(values))
    pass
```

Anyone knows the method of using iterative to come up with an answer?

Comment: Are you asking for a for loop?

Comment: What did you try ? Is it an assignment ?

Comment: What do u want exactly?

Comment: The `pass` after the `return` serves no useful purpose.

Comment: is using a for loop possible?

Comment: can specify your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find ***max/min*** via traversal/iteration - use the following approach:

```
def max_and_min(values):
    max_v = min_v = values[0]
    for v in values[1:]:
        if v < min_v:
            min_v = v
        elif v > max_v:
            max_v = v

    return (max_v, min_v)

l = [1,10,2,3,33]
print(max_and_min(l))
```

The output:

```
(33, 1)
```

Comment: I think instead of providing the solution for copying we should rather explain the solution so the OP can try to solve it himself/herself. This especially applies in cases like this, where the question is obviously based on a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine, but the `min` and `max` methods both loop through the tuple in order to find the smallest and biggest values respectively.

I think what you want is the following:

- define two variables: `smallest` and `biggest` and set both to the first element of the tuple
- loop through the tuple (`for number in values: ...`)
- compare each value to the current `smallest` and `biggest` using the "smaller than" `<` and "bigger than" `>` operators respectively.
- if any of the conditions apply, set the respective variable to the current element (`smallest = number`)

After the loop finishes, you will have the variables `smallest` and `biggest` filled with the respective min and max.

If you want to further optimise it, use an `if ... else...` instead of two `if`s. A maximal value cannot be the smallest value at the same time. (The only way for that is having only one distinctive number in the tuple and we already covered that case by setting the values to the first element in the beginning.)